# Setting a Text Area's text to align to the bottom

Tags: java, css, javafx, textarea, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a GUI with JavaFXML and I am using a TextArea in it. When adding text to a TextArea, it defaults to putting the text at the top, and I would like the text to start at the bottom, and be added below the previous text when I append it. I am trying to emulate a terminal if that helps.

Currently I'm using css to style the UI and change the coloring, which works great, I just cant get the text to obey. If there is a way to add a css property to the TextArea so the text aligns to bottom that would be great.

This is all my code is doing functionally, taking whatever I type in a TextField and appending it to the text area above, which is disabled to keep users from typing in it.

```
textarea.appendText("\n" + textfield.getText());
```

**PS** I have my code request focus on the text field like so:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            textfield.requestFocus();
        }
    });
}
```

But how would I set the focus back to textfield if the user clicks off of it? I want the text to always be entered into the text field when typing while my application is selected, but if you click the text field, focus is removed and keystrokes aren't entered anywhere.

Comment: Except it's not a duplicate because I'm using Java, not HTML, and this is faking it with padding. Meaning if I append text the view will be all skewed. If I fill the TextArea with stuff, I can scroll up until there is only one line of text in the TextArea. This isn't possible in a real terminal

Comment: There is no browser here. This is a standalone Java application, not JavaScript. It's compiling into a .class file. I'm using JavaFXML for the UI, which I see is modeled off of HTML but isn't the same thing.

Comment: ok.. Sorry. I m going to delete the comments then

Comment: Just because I'm unable to find a solution to your problem (:p): What terminal aligns its text to the bottom? Both the OS X terminal and the Windows command prompt has its text aligned to the top of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `TextArea` has this functionality. What you could do is implement your own class with the desired behaviour. Here's an example of what it could look like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class MCVE extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BtmAlignedTextArea area = new BtmAlignedTextArea();

            TextArea msgArea = new TextArea();
            msgArea.setPrefHeight(100);
            Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
            sendButton.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            sendButton.prefHeightProperty().bind(msgArea.heightProperty());

            HBox msgBox = new HBox(msgArea, sendButton);
            msgBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            msgArea.prefWidthProperty().bind(msgBox.widthProperty().subtract(sendButton.widthProperty()));
            msgArea.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
                if (e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                    sendButton.fire();
                }
            });

            sendButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                area.addRow(msgArea.getText());
                msgArea.clear();

                // This is just a fix because the caret positions itself on the
                // second row after msgArea has been cleared for some reason.
                Platform.runLater(() -> msgArea.positionCaret(0));
            });

            VBox root = new VBox(area, msgBox);

            area.prefHeightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().subtract(msgArea.heightProperty()));
            area.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
            msgBox.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class BtmAlignedTextArea extends VBox {
        private ArrayList<Label> rows = new ArrayList<Label>();

        public BtmAlignedTextArea() {
            this.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
            this.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        }

        public void addRow(String text) {
            Label label = new Label(text);
            this.getChildren().add(label);
            rows.add(label);
        }

        public ArrayList<Label> getRows() {
            return rows;
        }
    }
}
```